# Dim the display when app not used for a while

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to dim the phone screen when my app is running and if there are no touch events during a certain period of time (say 10 sec) and then make the screen brighter as soon anywhere on the screen is touched again.

After searching SO, It seems like I need to create a custom `UIApplication` in order to process all the touches. Below is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

@objc(MyApplication)

class MyApplication: UIApplication {

    override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {

        var screenUnTouchedTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.makeScreenDim), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

        // Ignore .Motion and .RemoteControl event simply everything else then .Touches
        if event.type != .touches {
            super.sendEvent(event)
            return
        }

        // .Touches only
        var restartTimer = true
        if let touches = event.allTouches {
            // At least one touch in progress? Do not restart timer, just invalidate it
            self.makeScreenBright()
            for touch in touches.enumerated() {
                if touch.element.phase != .cancelled && touch.element.phase != .ended {
                    restartTimer = false
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if restartTimer {
            // Touches ended || cancelled, restart timer
            print("Touches ended. Restart timer")
        } else {
            // Touches in progress - !ended, !cancelled, just invalidate it
            print("Touches in progress. Invalidate timer")
        }

        super.sendEvent(event)
    }

    func makeScreenDim() {
        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.1)
        print("makeScreenDim")
    }

    func makeScreenBright() {
        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
        print("makeScreenBright")
    }
}
```

The print out looks something like this:

```
makeScreenBright
Touches in progress. Invalidate timer
makeScreenBright
Touches ended. Restart timer
makeScreenDim
makeScreenDim
makeScreenDim
makeScreenDim
makeScreenDim
...
```

As you can see above there is big issue with the code, it seems like I am creating a new Timer for every touch event. I don't know how to create a static (only one) Timer in the UIApplication.

How should I be implementing only one timer in the correct way?

(I am using an Iphone7, latest version of swift and xcode)

Comment: Create it as class property, invalidate it first then replace with new timer

Comment: @Tj3n thanks but I am very new to swift could you give an example or edit the code above

Comment: when you need to end timer, call `screenUnTouchedTimer.invalidate()`, i see in your code you haven't called this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to invalidate the previously created timer somewhere, otherwise you will get your described behaviour.

Store it in a property on each call to sendEvent, so you can access it the next time the method is called.

```
class MyApplication: UIApplication {

var screenUnTouchedTimer : Timer?

override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {

screenUnTouchedTimer?.invalidate()
screenUnTouchedTimer = Timer ......
```